# How to get the URI to a theme without the domain. Example: /wp-content/themes/my-theme

Tags: theme-development

I basically want the output of `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`, but without http(s) and the domain.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you're looking for. You want to return two strings, one of which is "http://" or "https://" and the other is "/wp-content/themes/my-theme"?

Comment: Not quite. I want to get exactly what the get_stylesheet_directory_uri() function returns, just without "http(s)//:mydomain.com" and ONLY get, for example: /wp-content/themes/my-theme.

Comment: Gotcha. Your original post specifies _with_ the scheme, which is what confused me.

Comment: Sorry, mah bad.

Comment: [`get_stylesheet_directory()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory)?

Comment: get_stylesheet_directory() returns a file path, not a URI.

Comment: I added a question mark for a reason :) @ChrisCox

Comment: BTW - just to be nitpicky - removing schema and authority breaks the URI (Uniform Resource Identifier) definition, making what you get a path - just saying. @ChrisCox

Comment: Good point. I think I was stuck on URI from the original version of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), because it exists exactly for that reason:

```
$path = parse_url( get_stylesheet_directory_uri(), PHP_URL_PATH );
```

Chris Cox’ solution will fail when the `wp-content` directory runs under a different domain than the rest of the site.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this would be to regex it. Use preg_replace() or similar to trim the output of get_site_url() from the output of get_stylesheet_directory_uri().

Edit: actually, str_replace would do the job without resorting to regex.

```
str_replace(get_site_url(), '', get_stylesheet_directory_uri());
```

Comment: _The easiest way to do this would be to regex it._
Famous last words.

Comment: There you go, should be slightly faster without the regex.